# How to check if a FTP server supports EPSV (Extended Passive) mode

Tags: ftp

From [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/801514/in-ftp-what-are-the-differences-between-passive-and-extended-passive-modes), I now know what is the difference between `PASV` and `EPSV` modes. Is there a definitive way of knowing if the FTP server supports `EPSV`?

Is it enough to just check the response of the `EPSV` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send the `FEAT` command. Defined in [RFC 2389](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2389), it is the primary mechanism used by clients to discover supported features. IANA maintains a list of [FTP commands and their FEAT codes](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ftp-commands-extensions/ftp-commands-extensions.xhtml).

If the server says that FEAT itself isn't a recognized command, it is best to assume that the FEAT-negotiated extensions such as EPSV are not supported either.

As for directly trying `EPSV` (discovery by brute force), it *might work* in most cases but I think it also has a chance of triggering server or even router bugs, so I wouldn't use this method myself. Besides, you'll probably end up using FEAT for various other reasons anyway.